# Visual Studio 2017 - IntelliSense is missing: ObjectDescription, Comments, Exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 the IntelliSense menu is missing the Object Description, the Comments, and the Exceptions as per the following

[image]

If I do the same in Visual Studio 2015, then I see it.
[image]

I have checked the Settings, but nothing found to change that my C# works fine as VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I have opened an older Project with VS2017 that was build on .net 4.5.2 and the IntelliSense with all XML Comments works, I installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack und Language Packs and the Problem was fixed.

So my Problem was that the Developer Pack for .Net 4.6.2 was not installed on my machine, only the Redistributable Package was installed.

I hope this answer can help other people with the same mistake.